# Javascript rounding numbers issue with multiplication

Tags: javascript

So I am having issues with numbers:

I have a item, with a price of 483.65. I want to multiply this by 7. Expected result should be:

```
3385.55
```

However, Javascript reds this as:

```
3385.5499999999997
```

The number in the database is stored as a Float.

Here are screenshots to explain the situation better:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Quick fix: Round the number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

be careful with floating point math operations.
thats because of floating point standard used by js vm.
one trick I found to fix it without external libs is to multiple by 1k and than divid by 1k.
483.65 * 1000 * 7 / 1000
strange but always works.

Comment: And order would matter: `483.65*1000*7/1000 = 3385.55`, whereas `483.65*7*1000/1000 = 3385.5499999999997`.

Comment: of course. need to use the same order as i wrote in my comment.

Comment: This might work by coincidence, but you should not rely on that (read the IEEE 754 standard). Use `toFixed()`, integer arithmetic or an arbitrary precision library, depending on your requirements.